# Combining two variables for use in Twig

Tags: html, google-app-engine, twig

I'm using Google app engine and I'm trying to set the value of a textarea based on the concatenation of two string variables. Let's say I have 4 items, and each item has multiple fields. So in my Python I'm passing the dictionary `{ 'value0': newValue }`. I'm using a for loop (iterator value num) and I want to use in my HTML something equivalent to `{{ value }}{{ num }}` where the variable referenced is `value0`.

I've tried `{{ value~num }}` but nothing works. If I could use an array that would be even better - such as `{{ value[num] }}`

Comment: Do you mean you have variables like `value0`, `value1`, etc.?

Comment: Yes. If there's a better way to do this then that would be better. In truth I have variables `valueA1`,`valueA2`,`valueB1`,`valueB2`, etc. and need to be able to increment and access all of them.

Comment: Can you edit your question to `print_r` the variable to output, and the expected result? That's quite unclear to me ^^.

Comment: Your best option seem to be using an array, like `values["A1"]`, then you can generate the keys in the view.